# Make an object draw a line?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics

The question itself is really simple: How can I make the sphere draw a line?

[image]

The only idea I had was to use a particle system to create a trail of particles behind the sphere. This didn't work since I wasn't able to make the particles stay in place. I didn't find anything by using google so I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: You can do that with dynamic painting

Comment: watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcWXFtnh2bk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ***dynamic painting***.
[image]

Subdivide your cylinder to create a dense geometry. Give the ball a *subsurf modifier* and smooth it. Apply transformations to both objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
[image]

Select the *sphere* and enable ***dynamic paint*** in *Physics* header. Set it as a ***brush*** and play with the marked red settings pictured below.
[image]

Select *cylinder* and set its type to ***canvas***. Increase the *sub-steps* amount and check the *anti-aliasing* checkbox for smoother result.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make *brush _a* draw on *canvas_a* and *brush_b* draw on *canvas_b* but not *brush_a* on *canvas_b* nor *brush_b* on *canvas_a*? I hope this was somewhat understandable.

Comment: Nevermind found it out.

Comment: Sorry for spamming so much. :P But my problem now is that the dynamic paint isn't rendering. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I wasn't at home. Please check out how to render the dynamic paint here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66449/dynamic-paint-not-showing-in-rendered-image