# I can't see Dynamic Paint neither in viewport nor in render, why?

Tags: animation, dynamic-paint

I am trying to draw a line on an object with dynamic paint.

I am following this tutorial on my 2.8 Blender version.
[Make an object draw a line?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66417/make-an-object-draw-a-line)

I can't see any paint neither in viewport nor in render.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

The *Dynamic Paint* is stored as *Vertex Color* data. You need to create a vertex color attribute named "`dp_paintmap`". That's the default name.

It's defined in the *Canvas > Output* section. There just click the [+] button. It will create the vertex color attribute for you. Then it's located in the *[Object Data Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/object_data.html) > Vertex Color* section. (In Blender 3.x the section is called *Color Attributes*)

[image]

After that, you will see the paint when you enter the Vertex Paint mode or switch color to `Vertex` in *[Viewport Shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html)* options for `Solid` render mode.

Finally, to see the paint on the material you just need to mix the output of a *[Vertex Color Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/vertex_color.html)* with the color of the material in the Node Shader Editor.

Here is an older, complete **example**: [Dynamic Paint not showing in rendered image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66449/dynamic-paint-not-showing-in-rendered-image). It works in Blender 2.9+.

**Note:** The output of the *[Attribute Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html)* is the same as the *[Vertex Color Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/vertex_color.html)* in 2.9x/the *Color Attribute* node in 3.x. And *Dynamic Paint Output* is just called *Output* in Blender 2.8+.