# Animation does not work correctly

Tags: rendering, animation, bezier-curves, dynamic-paint

I have several problems with my animation after render.

1. I made an animation of tears using bezier curves. According to my plan, in the last frames mashes should go through another mesh puddle. But they just stick into this puddle the end of the animation. In the viewport, everything is fine and the tears disappear as I expected, it is a problem of rendering.
2. I also made an animation with dynamic paint and baked it. I checked for modifications, frames, everything was fine, animation worked in the viewport and did not after render. I tried to fix it, but something broke and animation doesn't work even with solid viewport.

I will be grateful for your help

[image: meshes stuck in puuddle]
[image: where they are should be]
[image: waves are not displayed anymore]

[my blender file](https://dropmefiles.com/9DLdC)

p.s i dont use blend-exchange because my file is too big and i dont want to mess around with it now

Comment: Hi! If you share a file I recommend taking the time and giving objects proper names. That makes it easier for other people to understand what's going on :-)

Comment: About your Qs 1) I don't know if this solves your problem but let's give it a try. When I hit F12 nothing renders. The reason is that you have a strip in the video editor and *my* output folder is empty. On *your* computer, you always will see the rendered images not what you see in the viewport because of the active *Post Processing > [X] Sequencer*. So either delete the images in the output folder or uncheck the [Sequencer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/render/output/properties/post_processing.html#bpy-types-rendersettings-use-sequencer) checkbox to re-render the actual animation

Comment: 2) a) Indeed there is something strange and broken regarding the cache of the *Dynamic Paint*. I have to remove and recreate the canvas then the cache works again. b) you haven't defined the vertex color attributes ("dp_paintmap" and "dp_wetmap"), and you didn't use them in the shader. In consequence, DP will show nothing even with a working cache. Have a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66500/107598) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197247/107598).